# Incorrect path in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file consists of the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) out.py?$1
```

`out.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

print("Content-type: text/plain")
print()
print(os.environ["QUERY_STRING"])
```

I've enabled Python to be used as CGI script in the Apache configuration and I've verified that it is working correctly. When I visit `https://example.net/foo/bar` I expect the body of the response to be "foo/bar". Unfortunately it is not, because the body contains the text "out.py". Any ideas what might be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ out.py?%1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried it, but the result is still the same.